# Dashed line with centred text

Tags: css

I am after a dashed line with a label in the middle. The dashed line needs to fit the width of the screen. I have conjured up the following.

```
<fieldset class="dashed">
<legend align="center">Some Centred Text</legend>
</fieldset>
```

```css
.dashed
{
border:0px;
border-top: 1px dashed;
}
```

Wonder if there is a better way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I were you, I use `div` and `span` for my markup:

```
<div class="dashed">
    <span>Some Centred Text</span>
</div>
```

And in CSS:

```
.dashed {
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #000;
    text-align: center;
    height: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.dashed span {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 0 5px;
}
```

Code snippet:

```css
.dashed {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #000;
  text-align: center;
  height: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.dashed span {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dashed">
  <span>Some Centred Text</span>
</div>
```

- Check the [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/68haQ/).

Comment: What difference does that really make to fieldset/legend?

Comment: @Ben From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset): _The HTML <fieldset> element is used to group several controls as well as labels (<label>) within a web form._ And it has several attributes too. And, the browser will add some default CSS to it, so for creating such a dashed-line, its not suitable.

Comment: i think if you not want to `text-align:center` then fieldset would be good